# Download more than 1000 images using BingImageCrawler in icrawler

Tags: python, web-crawler, bing

I am trying to download 3000 images for each keyword using BingImageCrawler but I am getting cut off at < 1000 images per keyword. The documentation says `To crawl more than 1000 images with a single keyword, we can specify different date ranges`. This works easily for GoogleImageCrawler because it supports a tuple of date ranges but BingImageCrawler doesn't (only supports “pastday”, “pastweek”, “pastmonth”, “pastyear”).

How can I set the configs such that I can get more than 1000 images per keyword? Also, if I need to do multiple request for each keyword, how can I set the date filter so that I get non-overlapping images? (Using any two of “pastday”, “pastweek”, “pastmonth”, “pastyear” will always result in overlapping images).